# Restrict an Image in my root directory to be accessed with URL when hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

An Image in my root directory is accessed with URL  when typed in browser when hosted in Azure App Service.
This should be restricted. I am looking for best possible approach to do so in Azure.

Comment: hi, you can restrict it with a simple script

Comment: what language you guys are using?

Comment: its .Net based Web App using c#